# Brew Doctor Error "Failed to update tap: caskroom/versions"

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I ran "brew doctor" and "brew update" and these error messages showed up:

> "Error: Failed to update tap: caskroom/versions"
>
> "Could not link caskroom/cask manpages to:
>     /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew-cask."

I don't know what it means and if I need to do anything about it.

I have no education in computer science. I use R, R Studio, and Sublime Text for writing code. I also played with Xcode to write an app. I honestly have no idea what Brew does or if I should even have it installed. I installed it because an undergrad computer science student was using it and recommended it.

Thanks for anyone who can provide any directions or advice.

Comment: Well, do you use caskroom ?

Comment: Does the issue arise when you run `brew doctor` or `brew update`?

Comment: I ran both brew doctor and brew update. I don't understand what caskroom is or what it does. The belief I had when installing Homebrew was that it would smooth out a lot of issues regarding third party apps I install on the Mac, especially those intended for coding and development. It turns out to be more complicated than expected.

I checked GItHub pages for common Homebrew problems and didn't find a solution related to these errors.

For now, nothing truly terrible is happening, so I assume it's not a serious concern. Thanks guys for responding.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
brew untap caskroom/homebrew-cask
brew uninstall --force brew-cask
brew update 
brew cleanup
brew cask cleanup
```

if it still gives an error 
check this link (https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/16094)